# Splitting an array according to the user input

Tags: java, arrays, integer

There is an integer array i.e `int[] integerArray = {3,7,-9,1,98,-5,0};`

A user will input a value (i.e 0) and the desired output should be 
all the values which are less than the input value should go left of the array and all 
the values which are greater than the input key should go right side of the array.

Desired output: `{-9,-5,0,1,3,7,98}`

It is not required that the values should be sorted, it could be : `{-5,-9,0,98,1,5,3}`.

My approach:

I am having to integer arrays and and I am comparing the key with the values of array
if its is smaller than input it will go to left array if it is greater than input it 
will go to right array. Please help me improve my logic as I know its not the proper approach 
to solve this program.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far. Please show us some code and explain where it fails.

Comment: Where is your logic now?

Comment: Your title is extremely bad..

Answer (score 1):

Just use  [Arrays#sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) after you added whatever value to the array:

```
int[] integerArray = {3,7,-9,1,98,-5,0};
Arrays.sort(integerArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you playing with qSort? Your code (pivot part of qSort algorithm)
could be like this:

```
int[] integerArray = {3, 7, -9, 1, 98, -5, 0}; 
int pivot = 0; // <- Value to compare with 

int left = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; ++i) {
  if (integerArray[i] <= pivot) { // or integerArray[i] < pivot - it's unclear from the question
    int h = integerArray[i];
    integerArray[i] = integerArray[left];
    integerArray[left] = h;

    left += 1;
  }
}
```